# C# saving to Firestore database (not realtime database)

Tags: c#, wpf, google-cloud-firestore

Hi ive created a C# WPF application which takes special order information, 9fields(all strings) and i have set it up to save to firebase realtime database.
My problem is that i would prefer the data to save to Firestore database instead because i have a web application reading from the firestore database.

This code configures the database but defaults on the realtime database

```
IFirebaseConfig Config = new FirebaseConfig
        {

            AuthSecret = "KKYIr2x----theAuthSecret---Fe4ifwwU1hUp",
            BasePath = "https://projectId.firebaseio.com",

        };
        public IFirebaseClient client;
```

This is the code to send to the database, its after the newOrder object is created using on button click

```
                SetResponse response = await client.SetAsync("EjsCustomerOrders" + id, newOrder);
                Order order = response.ResultAs<Order>();



                MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted");
                data.Orders.Add(newOrder);
                data.SaveChanges();
                ClearInputs();
            }
```

This works but i want to save the data to the Firestore database instead.
Any ideas??